# Flutter performance - one large file or bunch of smaller ones?

Tags: performance, flutter

I'm new to Flutter so I got this question while rewriting some of my Java apps in it.

Normally I separate stuff into class files that I structure with packages and it's fine. In Flutter there are some things like combining BottomNavigationBar with PageView and it's just tempting to write big parts of the app (like 90% of the UI) in one file (at least for me). What is the right way to provide optimal performance of the end product, does it impact it at all?

Clarification: to be clear I know the "right way" of coding. It is more about how Flutter handles such things. I'm curious about Flutter in particular, because in the aforementioned specific example with BottomNavigationBar it can be done in one file - so.. there's no performance gain if I separate the code for each tab versus doing it all in one .dart file?

Answer (score 0):

**The short answer is always make your code structure as modular as possible.There's no real performance issue to your app in writing your code in one big file but it is going to affect your performance in debugging your code later.**

> Writing all the UI code in one file is going to give you some real
> headache once your app scales and your code becomes spaghetti.
> Although it is ok to use one file for a much smaller app. But even
> with the smaller app just try to maintain your habit it's gonna
> benefit you in the long run.
>
> Also one big UI code file becomes a pain for anyone trying to
> understand your code some time in the future. So try to make your code
> modular .i.e break it down into small chunks of separate files when
> suited.

Comment: Thank you for answering the initial question, I've updated it a bit to make it more clear. I'm well aware of the basic principles of producing clean readable code, it's just the thing about the Flutter - I wanna know how it handles such things.